# How do I handle multiple select dropdown component with their values?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have created one component for select dropdown list. My requirement is to add more of these component when your press add row button. I am able to add this component on add row button press.

I am having trouble with their value. Example lets say there are four option ['audi', 'bmw', 'volvo', 'tesla']. When the user select any value out of these like "audi" and then press Add row button.

New drop list appear with only 3 values  ['bmw', 'volvo', 'tesla'] and now they have selected "bmw". My issue is when user again select value from the first/previous dropdown component - There should be only ['audi', 'volvo', 'tesla'], excluding "bmw". How can I achieve this?

I have created an array which store all other arrays option. Later when I connect to the API, I am going to create array of an object.

Please let me know. Thanks

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" />
    <button :disabled="isDisabled" @click="addRow">Add Row</button>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div v-for="(n, i) in defaultRow" :key="i">
            <DropDowns @dropDownSelect="onDropDownSelect" :lists="allLists[i]"></DropDowns>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import DropDowns from "./components/DropDowns.vue";

export default {
  name: "app",
  data() {
    return {
      defaultRow: 1,
      allLists: [["audi", "volvo", "mec", "toyota"]],
      selectedValue: ""
    };
  },
  components: {
    DropDowns
  },
  computed: {
    isDisabled() {
      return this.defaultRow === this.lists.length ? true : false;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addRow() {
      if (this.defaultRow < 4) {
        console.log('selectedValue',this.selectedValue)
        if (this.selectedValue) {
          this.allLists.push(this.allLists[this.defaultRow - 1].filter(l => l !== this.selectedValue));
          this.allLists[this.defaultRow - 1] = this.allLists[this.defaultRow - 1].filter(l => l === this.selectedValue )
          console.log("TCL: addRow -> this.lists", this.allLists);
        }
      }
    },
    onDropDownSelect(selected) {
      this.selectedValue = selected;
      console.log(
        "TCL: onDropDownSelect -> this.selectedValue",
        this.selectedValue
      );
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Dropdown component:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <select v-model="selected" @change="getValue">
      <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
      <option v-for="list in lists" :value=list :key=list>{{list}}</option>
    </select>
    {{selected}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['lists'],
    data() {
      return {
        selected: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      getValue() {
        this.$emit('dropDownSelect', this.selected)
      }
    }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Right now, once user select value from select. They can only see that value.

Comment: Use the [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method to remove the selected element. You can also use this to add an element if needsbe

Comment: I know how to use slice. Don't know how can I use it here

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it  :

check the sample : https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-5jbmz ;

I commented what i've changed above the line .... basically your main issue was that your `defaultRow` was not incrementing ....so you were just pushing an empty array to your `allLists`

Comment: Thx, However, this is not what i am aiming for. let's say user selected audi in first drop down and pressed add row. New dropdown compo is loaded. Now user selected volvo and pressed add row btn again. Now he wants to change value in first compo. Now he should only see  value which are not selected in other components like [audi, mec, toyota]. He can see his selected value though. Could you please guide me?